# how can i cancel the drag if the element is not over a specific element (placeholder) vuedraggable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Inside each item I created a placeholder where I want the element to only be dropped if the mouse is over the placeholder

> Tried to check on 'move' but once found the element the check stops working

Tried to check on 'move' but once found the element the check stops working

```
 move(evt) {
      let component = evt.relatedContext.component;
      if (evt) {
        let placeholder =
          evt.originalEvent.target.getAttribute("data-placeholder");

        console.log(placeholder);
        if (placeholder === null) {
          console.log("Não dropar");
          return false;
        }

        let groups = component.componentData.groups;
        let draggedGroup = evt.draggedContext.element.group;
        if (!groups.includes(draggedGroup)) {
          console.log("Não Pode");
          return false;
        }

      
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
```

**This approach didn't work**